# What is the alternative in HarmonyOS for postDelayed() in android?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am working on an HarmonyOS library that prompts users to review the app on the app gallery. I want to display a prompt thanking the user after he/she reviews the app and the prompt should fade after "int thanksDisplayTimeMs". In Android, it is implemented using

```
 postDelayed(new Runnable(){
     @Override
     public void run() {
     }
 }, thanksDisplayTimeMs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may can refer to `postTask` in `EventHandler`.

For Details, check [Docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/eventhandler-0000001054518858).